# How do I answer another python programs raw_input() request within a different file?

Tags: python, python-3.5

I understand this question is confusing, but I can't think of a better way to put it...

Let me explain, I have one python file that runs another python file through the execfile() command. It checks for error, but I want it to do it by itself, without me supervising. The file it checks for errors has raw_input() commands in it though, so when my main file checks for errors it forces me fill out the raw_input() and press enter in order for the script to continue.

I'm looking for a way to run another file with execfile() and automatically fill out the raw_input requests so I don't have to.

To explain:

main.py

```
while True:
    execfile('second.py') #Will stop for every raw_input(), loop stops too.
    # Looking for way to fix, so the raw_input is filled and loop continues automatically
```

second.py

```
print("Hello")
a = raw_input(">") #This will stop main.py from looping, how do I autofill this request from main.py?
print(a)
```

Comment: Actually it is still very confusing. Please give two sample programs to show what you aim to do.

Comment: then why do you not temporarily shortcut the `raw_input()` with constants\random values? having yet a third script does not help anyone.

Comment: Use `subprocess.Popen` probably

Comment: I put some example code on there. The first file runs the second, when the second asks for raw_input it stops the first file from looping. This is breaking my program, and I'm trying to figure out how to automatically fill out the raw_input() request the second file gives to the first file, through some magic code in the main file.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Pexpect.

Answer (score 2):

So this is not going to be the perfect workaround, but if you're using bash to run your scripts it's easy to just do

```
echo "2" | python b.py
```

where b.py is

```
execfile('a.py')
```

and a.py is

```
a = raw_input()
print a
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is great and very clever! Is there a way to maybe put 1000+ echo commands in one line? The way I'm looping through the program would require many.

Comment: @user3525745. `cat response_file` instead of `echo`, where `response_file` contains the lines you want to print.

Comment: Alternatively do the, loop in bash: `while true; do echo "2" | python a.py; done`

Comment: `for i in 2 3; do echo $i ; done | python b.py` and similar loops for however many variables you want work for two raw_inputs.

Comment: Thank you, I used the Windows version of cat, type, and got my program working wonderfully! Thanks for the help!